# Are 2 cheaper PSU's better than one more expensive one?

Tags: power-supply

I have hardware that requires 1300W.

If I buy 2 [750W PSU's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A00LR6G) for $70 each, wouldn't that be better than buying [ONE 1500W PSU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BH3Z84) for $299?

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I siphon off unused power from a PSU?](https://superuser.com/questions/1274853/can-i-siphon-off-unused-power-from-a-psu)

Comment: If you are going to re-ask the same question in slightly different form, then delete the old one.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - The author should improve the original question before submitting a duplicate question and/or removing the original question.  Users who ask low quality questions get themselves question banned fairly quickly by resubmitting questions and deleting questions.  *Although in this case the questions are not similar enough to warrant that advice.*

Comment: What does price have to do with the question?  Lower total price vs. higher total price is not an on-topic consideration here (and just a rhetorical question, anyway), and the hardware doesn't care what you paid for it.

Answer (score 2):

Most PCs can only use one Power Supply.  So unless this is server hardware and not PC hardware, you'd be stuck using just the one 1500W PSU.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some sort of load balancing equipment where both PSU's are hooked up fully (with the 20+4pin connectors), it's much better to run a single PSU.

PSUs are designed to handle a load that's dispersed across several outputs.  Depending on the protection options your PSU provides, if it detects a large uneven balance internally between the outputs, it will likely turn itself off.

If you're talking about 2 PSU's for one computer, that only works if it's a server and both PSUs can handle the full load, which are used as fail-overs, rather than load balancing.