# Can I siphon off unused power from a PSU?

Tags: power-supply, bitcoin

I have a 850W PSU of which I'm currently using 350W. I have another device that requires 1300W, so can I use the existing PSU and another 1000W PSU together to power the new device?

Comment: There are some DIY circuit board online. Do you want them to power a bitcoin mining machine?

Answer (score 4):

Not likely. PSU's are switching power supplies with internal voltage regulation, which makes paralleling them difficult. For example, if one supply outputs 4.99 V and the other 5.01 V, the higher voltage supply will attempt to provide all the current. For noncritical applications, e.g. electroplating, a resistor in series with each supply could force current to be shared more equitably, but that won't work for IC's that need carefully controlled voltage.